# php - can't convert date from string

Tags: php, date

I want to get this date's timestamp from string. I'm trying:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2015-05-18T23:45:21.604Z");
```

But it returns nothing. I don't know which format is this.

Comment: Just look up the format specifiers: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: you might wanna check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238992/converting-string-to-date-and-datetime
The first answer splits the process in two pices. With that the debugging should be easier.

Comment: the problem is I don't know the format. I can use `substr()` to get only first chars from date string, but guess this is not the correct way to do this

Comment: You ask a new question, but you don't even end your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31302585/3933332

Comment: Can you give more information on where did you get that Date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/M/Y:H:i:s', '2015-05-18T23:45:21.604Z');
$date->getTimestamp();
```